# How to obtain consistent javascript prompt string and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I have a paragraph, which I would like to edit using javascript `prompt` function.
All work ok while I didn't enter `<` or `>`. They looks good in html, but when I would like to edit them again, I see ugly `&gt;` and `&lt;`

The issues can be easy reproduced via following scenario:

1. press Edit-button,
2. Enter string `<<<>>>`.
3. press Edit-button again.

You will see ugly prompt symbols in dialog.

In prompt-dialog ugly un-escaped symbols appear.

In fact before passing innerHTML to prompt function I should un-escape characters, how could this be done?

Part of my code following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function edit()
  {
    str = document.getElementById('par').innerHTML;
    str = prompt(str, str);
    document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = str;
  }
</script>


<p id="par">aaa</p>

<input type="button" onclick="edit()" value="Edit" />
```

I prefer API-function instead of manual replacing `gt;` an `&lt;`.
jquery solution is also interseting for me.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Geoff's answer. Also note that using `prompt` is frowned upon these days. IE7 and later completely disallow `prompt` by default, which makes it unusable for most sites. Also it's a modal popup window, which no-one really likes anyway. Consider using an in-page pop-on-top form instead.

Comment: @bobince Thanks a lot for additional info. Could you suggest good article or site where I can read about it?

Comment: see eg. http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/ie7_javascript_prompt%28%29_alternative.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very easy to use

Comment: Also, `window.prompt` is essentially unusable on the general web these days, since IE 7 disabled it by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want just the textual content, then you should use the textual value rather than the innerHTML property.

In jQuery you can do this like so:

```
var paragraph = $("#par");
var stringValue = paragraph.text();
stringValue = prompt( "Please ammend your text", stringValue );
paragraph.text( stringValue );
```